# ASP vNext and PostgreSql

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

exists currently any way, how to communicate with PostgreSql database, when I want to use ASP.NET vNext? I'm looking for solution, which will work mainly on linux.

EF7 supports only MS SQL a SqlLite now and Npgsql isn't ported for ASP.NET vNext.

Thanks

Comment: There was Redis and SqlLite implementation for beta1, if you want I maintain the Redis implementation. It will be soon ready for beta3. check out my gitub https://github.com/aguacongas/EntityFramework. Or you can implement your own PostgreSql implementation...

Comment: My EntityFramework.Redis is available on myget for beta3 add https://www.myget.org/F/chatle/api/v2/ in your NuGet feeds

Answer (score 3):

Instead of EF7 you can use NHibernate together with Fluent NHibernate. Npgsql is also working well on ASP.NET 5 (vNext) on Linux. Here is a complete example of [ASP.NET vNext application with NHibernate + PostgreSQL working on ubuntu server](http://druss.co/2015/04/vnext-use-postgresql-fluent-nhibernate-from-asp-net-5-dnx-on-ubuntu/).

Answer (score 2):

I'm still testing this out (on `dnx-coreclr-win-x64.1.0.0-rc2-16177` at the moment), but they have made a lot of progress since @bricelam answered.  They now have some [EF7 docs](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/ef7.html) including some on [CoreCLR support](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/coreclr.html)

Here's part of my
project.json:

```
"dependencies": {
  "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc2-*",
  "EntityFramework.Core": "7.0.0-rc2-*",
  "EntityFramework.Relational": "7.0.0-rc2-*",
  "EntityFramework7.Npgsql": "3.1.0-rc1-2",
},
"frameworks": {
  "dnxcore50": {}
}
```

<strike>You will probably need to add https://www.myget.org/F/npgsql-unstable/api/v3/index.json to your NuGet feeds in order to pull that package.</strike>
*EDIT*: I now specify an exact version of `EntityFramework7.Npgsql": "3.1.0-rc1-2"` and use only this feed in my NuGet.config:  <strike>https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetrelease/api/v3/index.json</strike>

*EDIT*: This is all now available in https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

In Startup.cs:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddEntityFramework()
            .AddNpgsql()
                .AddDbContext<YourDbContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql("your connectionString"))
            ;
    }
```

Comment: I dont think you need the MyGet source

Comment: Thanks @ErikEJ I tested this on dnx-coreclr-win-x64.1.0.0-rc2-16302 and edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The Npgsql community is [working on an EF7 provider](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/249). I'm sure the code is available somewhere if you want to start using it.

Comment: Yes, thanks, but support for .NET Core is plan as a feature - https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/471